# problem with prepare statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select fname,lname, "
                    + "sportman_code,start,finish,salary,amount,number,pnumber "
                    + "from sportman,customer "
                    + "where customer.customer_code = "
                    + "sportman.customer_code order by ? limit ?,?");



            preparedStatement.setString(1, "fname");
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, 0);
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, 9);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

order by didn't work.
why?

when i put fname instead ? it work correctly.

```
"sportman.customer_code order by fname limit ?,?");
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind in identifiers like table names or column names, only values that you want to insert, compare, etc

Answer (score 2):

Your ORDER BY works, but not as you expect it to. When you use

```
 preparedStatement.setString(1, "fname");
```

it will make an ORDER BY like this

```
 ORDER BY 'fname'
```

and not as you expect

```
 ORDER BY fname
```

The code in your question will then be like sorting a package of M&Ms alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

Binding works for literals in the query, not for keywords or identifiers.  You'll need to use another approach for sanitizing the sort field if you want it to be dynamic.